# Populating a List(Of String) from a Datatable using LINQ in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, linq

So I have a DataTable that looks more or less like

```
 Column 0      |  Column 1 
 Something     |  Something Else 
 Another Thing |  Another Something Else
```

And I want to put everything in column 0 into a List(Of String)

I could do

```
Dim returnValue as List(Of String)    
For Each r As DataRow In dt.Rows
     returnValue.Add(r.Item(0).ToString)
Next
```

But that's old and busted.  I want to do

```
returnValue = (From r In dt.Rows Select DirectCast(r, DataRow).Item(0)).ToList
```

But that gives me a list(of Object).

How can I directly create a list(of String)

(the DirectCast is there because I have Option Strict On)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit to @Heinzi's answer. I used it to code my own example which I will post below. It is a complete VB Program Example which may be better for less advanced users.

I have tested it and verified it is working. Thank you!

```
Sub Main
    
    Dim dataTable1 As New DataTable
    Dim listOfString As New List(Of String)
    
    dataTable1.Columns.Add("DT Column Title" , GetType(String))
    
    dataTable1.Rows.Add("1234")
    dataTable1.Rows.Add("1235")
    dataTable1.Rows.Add("1236")
    dataTable1.Rows.Add("1237")
    
    listOfString = (From item In dataTable1.AsEnumerable() Select item.Field(Of String)(0)).ToList()
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Might be neater as Method Syntax, which would look something like: `dataTable1.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(x) x(0).ToString()).ToList()` - also, it's a bit cleaner to just .ToString() the object you get out of indexing row(0) rather than `Field`ing it. If you use strongly typed datatables it looks even nicer; normal one might say: `strongDt.Select(Function(x) x.Column0).ToList()` - column0 being the name of the property (e.g. FirstName, PostCode, Status, whatever)

Answer (score 8):

It is in an datarow collection so we need to cast it out.

[Cast](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fvstudio%2Fbb341406%2528v%3Dvs.100%2529.aspx&ei=4FFwVbCKI4m8yQTAn4PoCg&usg=AFQjCNGKqji7P3-ii2uYKbnVDdp0VthEVA&sig2=bgWFYf2_UWVw-5kHQmVDpw)

The function in the `Select` asks which field do you want from the casted object.

```
returnValue = dt.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).Select(Function(dr) dr(0).ToString).ToList
```

Answer (score 6):

`dt.Rows` is from before the time of .NET generics, so it won't return an `IEnumerable(Of DataRow)`. However, there is an extension method, [DataTable.AsEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which does exactly what you need:

```
returnValue = (From r In dt.AsEnumerable() Select r.Field(Of String)(0)).ToList()
```

Note that my example also uses the [DataRow.Field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method, which allows type-safe access to DataRow fields without needing an explicit cast (even with Option Strict On).

Comment: @George: What makes you think so? I use this pattern all the time in my .NET 3.5 projects. Maybe you are missing a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`?

Comment: I've tried the code and its not working. I have System.Data.DataSetExtensions reference, but I get compilation error `'ToList' is not a member of 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection(Of String)'` PS: its a website, if that makes any difference.Im using VS express 2013 and the project is .NET framework 3.5

Comment: @George: This should work, since `EnumerableRowCollection(Of T)` implements `IEnumerable(Of T)`, and, thus, the [Enumerable.ToList extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.90).aspx) should world. Maybe you are missing a reference to `System.Core` or an `Imports System.Linq` statement?

Comment: I've got `System.Core` ref, but didn't have `Imports System.Linq` - that fixed the compilation error. Very weird! Thank you Heinzi

Comment: @George: You're welcome. In VB, you can set global imports in the project properties. If your project started out as a 2.0 project and later got upgraded to 3.5, it's possible that the System.Linq import is not there.