# C# DataTable Show Single Row in Console

Tags: c#, datatable, row, console.writeline

I have searched high and low for a method to show the entire row of a C# datatable, both by referencing the row number and by simply writing the row contents to a string variable and showing the string in the console. I can specify the exact row and field value and display that value, but not the whole row. This is not a list in C#, this is a datatable.

For the simple code below, the output I get for the first WriteLine is "Horse", but the second two WriteLine commands, I get the console output of "System.Data.DataRow" instead of the whole row of data.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Threading;

namespace DataTablePractice
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Create a DataTable.
            using (DataTable table = new DataTable())
            {
                // Two columns.
                table.TableName = "table";
                table.Columns.Add("Number", typeof(string));
                table.Columns.Add("Pet", typeof(string));

                // ... Add two rows.
                table.Rows.Add("4", "Horse");
                table.Rows.Add("10", "Moose");

                // ... Display first field of the first row in the console
                Console.WriteLine(table.Rows[0].Field<string>(1));

                //...Display the first row of the table in the console
                Console.WriteLine(table.Rows[0]);

                //...Create a new row variable to add a third pet
                var newrow = table.Rows.Add("15", "Snake");
                string NewRowString = newrow.ToString();

                //...Display the new row of data in the console
                Console.WriteLine(NewRowString);

                //...Sleep for a few seconds to examine output
                Thread.Sleep(4000);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Inspect `table.Rows[0]` [in the debugger](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/). Notice it's not any kind of string? If you want to catenate the string field values of this row you have to do that yourself; there are [many ways of doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30644853/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run this:

```
Console.WriteLine(table.Rows[0]);
```

It's in effect calling this:

```
Console.WriteLine(table.Rows[0].ToString());  // prints object type, in this case a DataRow
```

If it were your own class, you could [override ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method) to return whatever you need, but you don't have that option with the `DataRow` class. And so it uses the default behavior as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.8#remarks):

> Default implementations of the Object.ToString method return the fully qualified name of the object's type.

You could iterate through the columns, like this for example:

```
var row = table.Rows[0];
for (var i = 0; i < row.Count; i++)
    Console.Write(row[i] + " : ");
```

Or, a shorter way to print them all out:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" : ", table.Rows[0].ItemArray));
```

Given your data, maybe you just want to reference the two fields?

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    Console.WriteLine($"You have {row[0]} {row[1]}(s).");

// You have 4 Horse(s).
// You have 10 Moose(s).
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Then, I figured out if I use Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", newrow.ItemArray));, it will then write row that was created with the newrow variable to the console. It works very well. :-)

Answer (score 0):

While the answer here is excellent, I highly recommend using  `Spectre.Console`

It is an open source library that helps you generate highly formatted console output.
With this, the code to write the output simply becomes:

```
public static void Print(this DataTable dataTable)
{
    var table = new Table();
    table.AddColumn("#");
    for (int i=0;i<dataTable.Columns.Count;i++)
    {
        table.AddColumn(dataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<dataTable.Rows.Count;i++)
    {
        var values = new List<string>
        {
            i.ToString()
        };
        for (int j = 0; j < dataTable.Columns.Count;j++)
        {
            values.Add(dataTable.Rows[i][j]?.ToString()??"null");
        }
        table.AddRow(values.ToArray());
    }
    AnsiConsole.Write(table);
}
```

[image]