# VB.NET selecting multiple columns of MySql table simultaneously into lists

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net

I have a MySQL table that looks like this (attached below).

I want to simultaneously select (in a single SQL Query) multiple columns (`id`, `Last Name`, and `username`) and import into them into different lists of strings the values if they meet a certain condition (in this case, where `color="blue"`.

```
+----+------------+-----------+----------+----------------+
| id | First Name | Last Name | Username | Favorite Color |
+----+------------+-----------+----------+----------------+
|  1 | John       | Smith     | jsmith   | Blue           |
|  2 | Avery      | Nelson    | aNelson  | Red            |
|  3 | Jack       | Brooklyn  | jBrook   | Blue           |
|  4 | Arnold     | Nam       | aNam     | Blue           |
|  5 | Charlie    | Smith     | cSmith   | Orange         |
+----+------------+-----------+----------+----------------+
... Continued
```

I am trying to select all the required data that meet the condition where `color=Blue` with the MySQL query of `` SELECT id, Last Name, username FROM `myTable` WHERE color="Blue" ``. Once this data is selected,  I want to import each selected column that meets the color requirement into separate lists.

For example, list `FirstName` should be list of strings "John, Jack, Arnold" (in that order) and `Username` list should contain "jsmith, jBrook, aNam" etc. In the end, I want to be able to produce three lists that contain these values which meet the `Favorite Color` condition in the MySQL database of `Blue`. How can I do this?

I know that I can make three separate reader queries but I want to do them all in one to save time.

Answer (score 0):

You have not posted VB code so I'm not sure how you intend to use the results but you could load the whole table to a Datatable (unless it is really big), then use [Dataview.RowFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.rowfilter?view=netframework-4.8) to filter your data with different criteria **in-memory**, without making any further request to the database backend.

You can see an example in VB.net [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/VB/0480__Database-ADO.net/UseDataViewtofilterdatatable.htm)

Then you could use LINQ for example to generate a list of string from a datatable or view, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63622052/6843158) for an example.

Comment: I know I can select a single value like this ``Dim reader As MySqlDataReader`` and using ``reader(0)`` but not multiple at once.

Comment: @Samor1922 Did you look at the links provided?